# Linkers and loaders , Where are they stored?

Tags: operating-system

Where are linker , loaders and compilers located in a processor ?

Like linker are present in gcc but I cannot find for Loaders or Compilers .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker is just a program. It can be anywhere and there can be more than one linker on a system.

The same goes for compilers. They are just programs. There are often many compilers on a system. They can be wherever programs are stored.

The loader is usually a system service routine linked to the kernel.